# Sharing Reliable Collections across partitions

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to share data across Service Fabric partitions using Reliable Collections?
What would be the best approach to run arbitrary number of instances of a CPU/network -bound service that needs to share a small amount of data to be used for custom partitioning algorithm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reliable Collections themselves don't share state across partitions, no. But there are a couple ways you can share data depending on the nature of that data:

If the data you need to share is "dynamic" meaning it can change at runtime (e.g., due to user input), then you'd need to encapsulate that data in a separate service of its own, and provide an API for other services to access it. This would be accessible by any other service or application.

If the data you need to share is "static" meaning it doesn't change at runtime, then you can include it in the service as a [data package or config package](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-application-model/#describe-a-service). These packages can be updated individually and separately from the service code without stopping or restarting the service. The same data/config package is available to all partitions of a service, but it is not directly accessible to other services or applications.

Comment: Thank you for the outline!
For my implementation I will have a "scheduler" service with an API exposed that workers would consume in order to distribute tasks.